# pandas - Return all entries when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data of 35k entries, I want to track only those Event_Action entries which have 0 in Event_Label and export them.
Condition is : if an entry 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us has 0 **return all results** and 1099-sales-jobs:us does't contain 0 , so we dont need this.

What have I tried so far is first

- filter all Event_Action entries which have 0 against them and create a new sheet/table

`df1 = pd.read_excel(pwd + "/zero_instance.xlsx")`

`df2 = pd.read_excel(pwd + "/All Last 7 days data rcom.xlsx")`

- then `df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='Event_Action', right_on='Event_Action')`

But its returning me only first instances of each row. **I need all instances when condition is met.**

Here's the sample of the data I'm working on.

| Event_Action | Event_Label |
| --- | --- |
| 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us | 0 |
| 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us | 20000 |
| 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us | 42323 |
| 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us | 72639 |
| 100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us | 73898 |
| 100-genuine-online-data-entry-jobs:us | 122299 |
| 1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us | 0 |
| 1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us | 568 |
| 1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us | 2004 |
| 1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us | 3001 |
| 1099-sales-jobs:us | 1721341 |
| 1099-sales-jobs:us | 1779187 |
| 10th-pass:in | 3870 |
| 1120:in | 11 |
| 1120:in | 25 |
| 12-pass:in | 474 |
| 12th-pass:in | 7 |
| 12th-pass:in | 230 |
| 12th-pass:in | 4469 |
| 12th-pass-best:in | 143 |
| 12th-pass-fresher-jobs:us | 703 |
| 12th-pass-patanjali:in | 0 |
| 12th-pass-patanjali:in | 97 |
| 12th-pass-patanjali:in | 102 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using groupby and transform

```
# Choose rows whose min Event_Label for the group is zero.
df_result = df[df.groupby('Event_Action')['Event_Label'].transform('min')==0]
```

---

```
print(df_result)

                                         Event_Action  Event_Label
0   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us            0
1   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        20000
2   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        42323
3   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        72639
4   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        73898
6                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us            0
7                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us          568
8                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us         2004
9                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us         3001
21                             12th-pass-patanjali:in            0
22                             12th-pass-patanjali:in           97
23                             12th-pass-patanjali:in          102
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data_string = """    Event_Action   Event_Label
100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us   0
100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us   20000
100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us   42323
100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us   72639
100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us   73898
100-genuine-online-data-entry-jobs:us   122299
1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us    0
1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us    568
1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us    2004
1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us    3001
1099-sales-jobs:us  1721341
1099-sales-jobs:us  1779187
10th-pass:in    3870
1120:in 11
1120:in 25
12-pass:in  474
12th-pass:in    7
12th-pass:in    230
12th-pass:in    4469
12th-pass-best:in   143
12th-pass-fresher-jobs:us   703
12th-pass-patanjali:in  0
12th-pass-patanjali:in  97
12th-pass-patanjali:in  102
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), sep='\s+')

# Solution
list_target = df[df['Event_Label'] == 0]['Event_Action'].to_list()
df_result = df[df['Event_Action'].isin(list_target)]
```

```
print(df_result)
                                         Event_Action  Event_Label
0   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us            0
1   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        20000
2   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        42323
3   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        72639
4   100-genuine-data-entry-jobs-without-investment:us        73898
6                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us            0
7                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us          568
8                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us         2004
9                            1099-bookkeeping-jobs:us         3001
21                             12th-pass-patanjali:in            0
22                             12th-pass-patanjali:in           97
23                             12th-pass-patanjali:in          102
```